# “Safe handle has been closed” Thread abort: can program crash be avoided?

Tags: c#, multithreading, dll, reflection, crash

Im using undetermined DLLs which can use undetermined resources such as a COM port. 
Some DLL methods don't have their own timeouts, so i am forced to abort the execution thread. 
But if the thread is using a resource such as a COM port, and i abort the thread, my program crashes with the error “Safe handle has been closed”. I know why this happens but is there any way to catch this exception or skip it, rather than an actual crash?

Comment: What dll? Aborting thread is last resort, the crash chance is the cost. Could you perhaps try to [load dll into another `AppDomain`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/88717/1997232) and unload it instead of aborting?

Comment: the dll is unknown!!.
interesting idea about another AppDomain, i'm trying to look into it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:
Running the code in a separate AppDomain bypasses the exception and crash - thanks to Sinatr in the comments.

Code example. Before (crashed)

```
Work work = new Work();
Thread execThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(work.COM_StartCommand));
execThread.Start("COM4");

Thread.Sleep(5000);
execThread.Abort();

for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("bump" + i); //crashes around iteration 20
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

After: (never crash)

```
using (Isolated<Work> isolated = new Isolated<Work>())
{
    Thread TestThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(isolated.Value.COM_StartCommand));
    TestThread.Start("COM4");

Thread.Sleep(5000);
TestThread.Abort();
}

for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("bump" + i);
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

Inspired by https://bitlush.com/blog/executing-code-in-a-separate-application-domain-using-c-sharp.
Now I just need to pass around variables.